# Java Runtime issue with passing arguements which includes spaces?

Tags: java, python

I have a python program where i am taking arguments from command line, the following python script will be run using JAVA code with runtime,

From Ubuntu Terminal :

```
python3 testingArg.py "My String With Spaces"


Import sys
print(sys.argv[1])
```

It's print's **`My String With Spaces`**

Java Code:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python3 testingArg.py "+"\"My String With Spaces\"");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        while((s = in.readLine())!=null) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
```

Print's out as **`"My"`**, and the rest of the string is truncated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command string is tokenized into arguments using a default tokenizer, which splits on whitespace only - no consideration is given to quotes.

In my opinion you are better off doing the tokenization yourself (which is trivial since you know you have one argument, so there's no code required) and using the [array form of exec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String%5B%5D)).

```
String args[] = { "python3",  "testingArg.py" , "My String With Spaces" };
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(args);
```

The "command string" form that you're currently using is essentially tokenizing the string into an array for you, but it's using an algorithm you're not happy with, so skip that and make the appropriate array yourself.